# convert special character to respective language

Tags: html, web, encoding

> I copied some text from the local language website Ex:eenadu.net
>   & if I paste that text in MS word, it is showing some special symbols:

```
∞_çáêà◊§
```

How do I convert it to so that it looks/reads the same as the source form where it was copied?

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting into a simple text editor. If "Paste and match style" is available then use that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install respective language package for your MS word. You can learn how to install new language from [here](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Enable-the-use-of-other-languages-in-your-Office-programs-663d9d94-ca99-4a0d-973e-7c4a6b8a827d?CorrelationId=a275f5fc-6c5e-4c1f-b324-ffb15f72c9e5&ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU).